# Batch convert smd to fbx files

Tags: python, export, import, conversion

I have thousands of .smd files I need to convert to .fbx files. I have an add-on that lets me import .smd files, but going one by one will obviously take forever. I need the script to search the main directory and all sub-directories for the .smd files.

I'm assuming this is how the script would work:

- Get main directory and sub-directories
- Put all of the .smd files in a database or something
- Factory Restart Scene
- Delete all objects in the scene
- Import a .smd file
- Export the .smd file as a .fbx without replacing the original
- Remove from list in the database?
- Loop back to the beginning until no files are left?

I know nothing about python, please help me.

Comment: This is perhaps a better question for stack overflow.

Answer (score 4):

Python isn't hard to start learning, try [this tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). You can use the [python console](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/python_console.html) in blender if you don't have python already installed.

You don't need to create a database as you can walk through all files in the directories and just use the filesystem as a todo list. This is the basics of what you want to do but you may want to make some adjustments, you will at least have to swap `bpy.ops.import_scene.obj` for the smd importer that you have.

```
import bpy
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/smd/files'):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith('smd'):
            # delete everything
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
            bpy.ops.object.delete()
            # adjust this to match the import smd operator
            bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=os.path.join(root, name))
            # export as fbx
            bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=os.path.join(root, name+'.fbx'))
```

You can paste this into blender's [text editor](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/text_editor.html), edit and then click the run script button.